# Log fille from TraceSource contains "Standard ACE DB"

Tags: c#, .net, logging, tracesource

My application uses TraceSource to log events and information. Somehow it dosent work on a certain computer and writes junk data.
The log file begins with `Standard ACE DB` and contains all kind of weird data. It looks like [this file](http://www.library.illinois.edu/sc/software_guides/DatabaseDesignWorkshop.accdb) I found on google.

My application is written in C# in .NET 4.5 and the file is created using TraceSource with this configuration `<add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="logfile.log"  traceOutputOptions="DateTime"/>`

Why does this happen?

Comment: That's an Access 2007 or newer database file.

Comment: I'd try deleting that file and letting the app recreate it. Sounds like the file already existed from some other app?

Comment: This can't possibly be related to Systems.Diagnostics tracing (according to the config you show). Do you have any other system diagnostics listeners registered? Do you have anything in your app that is creating ms-access databases and happens to be calling it logfile.log?

Comment: @DavidG I already tried that. I deleted the log file but the application dosen't recreate it. But when I made a new empty file (new text document and renamed the extentsion) it filled it with data similar to the file in the link. I also tried moving the application in diffrent folders and I got the same result.

Comment: @MatthewMartin nothing in the app uses external files (other than app.config). And no thats the only listener for that source, the next row also deletes the default listener. I do have another source, but its kinda the same thing, with only a `TextWriterTraceListener`.